# Dataset for NLP Text Summarization

Tags: data-request, nlp

Looking for a dataset for NLP Text Summarization consisting of

- articles and their headlines
- long news articles
- summaries of articles
- sentences extracted from user reviews on a given topic
- interviews
- long Conversations

Any of the above text database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kaggle is a great place to start. Here's one: https://www.kaggle.com/sunnysai12345/news-summary